# Passing Null value to Constructors with Object and String return String. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have the following C# code wherein I'm trying to call a constructor with null as its value.

Now, I have 2 Parameterized constructors, one with parameter type object and the other with string. Now, when I run this code, I get **String** as output. What I fail to understand is that I should be getting **Object** as an output which is base class object. WHY is this happening??

Also, If I create a third constructor like so:

```
public Program(int? c)
        {
            int? c1 = c;
            Console.WriteLine("Nullable int");
        }
```

Why do I recieve a Compile time error : `Error  1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ConsoleTest.Program.Program(string)' and 'ConsoleTest.Program.Program(int?)'    D:\VisualStudio2013\Projects\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\Program.cs 30  26  ConsoleTest`

**My C# Console App**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public Program(object a)
        {
            object a1 = a;
            Console.WriteLine("Object");
        }
        public Program(string b)
        {
            string b1 = b;
            Console.WriteLine("String");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Program pr = new Program(null);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: null isn't specified to be a object in the C# specification. I am not sure, but I think I recall, that the compiler tries to get the closest fit, and with that, the most specific definition. Ofcourse this is an edge case

Comment: When there is ambiguous, compiler chooses more specific type. Thus it chooses string in this case.

Comment: BTW I tried and passing `(Object)null` will call the object constructor. Of course that's even weirder than passing `null`.

Comment: Ok, what if I create a third constructor say    `Public Program(int? c){Console.WriteLine("Nulable Int")}` , it doesnt compile. Why so?

Comment: @abhinavchat with the third constructor it doesn't compile because it can't choose between the one with the `string` and the one with the `int?` (ambigous call), because `int?` and `string` have the same "level of specificity" compared to `object`